# An infinite basis for an ad hoc vector space

Tags: vector-spaces, infinitary-combinatorics, algebraic-combinatorics

To prove a combinatorial identity I'm building an ad hoc vector space that I will define below.

First, I define the set of **Pseudo Power Series**.
        A Pseudo Power Series (pps) $\alpha$ is an infinite sequence of real numbers $a_0, a_1, a_2, \dots$ denoted by $\alpha = (a_0, a_1, a_2, \dots)$, in which the order of the elements $a_0, a_1, a_2, \dots$ matters. We will denote by PPS the set of all pps.

Before going any further, let us set $f_0 = (1, 0, \dots, 0, \dots)$ and, in general,
    \begin{align*}
  f_i = (0, 0, \dots, a_{i-1} = 0, a_i = 1, a_{i+1} = 0, \dots).
 \end{align*}
    Moreover, we set $(0, 0, \dots, 0, \dots) = \boldsymbol{0}$ and $(1, 1, \dots, 1, \dots) = \boldsymbol{1}$. Finally, it's immediate to see that for any $f_i$, $f_j$ it holds
    \begin{align*}
 f_i * f_j =\begin{cases}
 f_i & \text{if } i = j\\
 \boldsymbol{0} & \text{if } i \neq j.\\
 \end{cases}
\end{align*}

We also define the **scalar multiplication**
    \begin{align*}
  \cdot : \mathbb{R} \times (\text{PPS}, +, \boldsymbol{0}) \rightarrow (\text{PPS}, +, \boldsymbol{0})
 \end{align*} for $r \in \mathbb{R}$, and $\alpha \in$ PPS as
    \begin{align*}
  r \cdot \alpha = (ra_0, ra_1, \dots, ra_i, \dots).
 \end{align*}

Now we come to my question: I thought that the set $\{f_0, f_1, \dots, f_k, \dots\}$ could be considered as a **basis** for the vector space $(\text{PPS}, +, \boldsymbol{0})$, but it is not true. To be a basis it has to span every element of PPS, but it is not possible: no finite linear combination of scalars and element of that basis can span every element of PPS.

So my question is: how can I extend the concept of basis for this infinite dimensional vector space? Do you know a way? Maybe if I use modules or other structures I can use infinite linear combinations? Thank you a lot.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Your vector space does have a basis, but not one that's easy to come by. You can read about it if you search for _Hamel basis_ and follow a link that matches your level of mathematical sophistication. Consider http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~kesmith/infinite.pdf

Comment: Thank you. I will read the pdf you have posted. In particular "Example 2" seems to represent my case.